# Do I need to re-deploy my cpu pinned VMs after enabling hyper-threading?

Tags: cpu, openstack, kvm, numa, hyperthreading

I have openstack running and kvm VMs are scheduled with cpu pinning. I have some requirement to enable hyper-threading but will this require redeploying the VMs due to the fact that the cores count and numbering will change?

Answer (score 0):

No, you will just adjust the domain xml files with updated pinning strategies. If your worried, I would remove CPU Pinning and make sure VM's boot fine before enabling Hyperthreading. Then after enabling you can mess around with domain xml. No need to 'Re-Deploy'